# Fetch data from ES and save to HDFS as Avro (Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Spark and Scala, so I have a really basic question. I have Spark 1.5.2 and Scala 2.10.4. I created the configuration that allowed me to fetch some data as JSON from ES, directly when launching `spark-shell` using the `--config` command; I also imported the `--jar` of `elasticsearch-hadoop`. Once I launched Spark, I did the following:

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
val rdd = sc.esRDD("my-index")
```

If I do `rdd.getClass` I get the following result:

```
res9: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef])]] = class org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.ScalaEsRDD
```

I suppose that it means that I have a List of Tuple with a String (document ID, I don't need it) and a Map (the JSON itself).

Now I would like to extract the Map with the JSON, create a schema and put the data to HDFS in Avro format.

I tried to do `val rdd_res = rdd.take(10)` to fetch only 10 record for testing purpose, that with `rdd_res.getClass` I get

```
res11: Class[_ <: Array[(String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef])]] = class [Lscala.Tuple2
```

Here I am quite stucked, due to my inexperience with Spark and Scala. How can I extract the Map from each value of the Array? Next, how can I save the result as an Avro to HDFS?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Even partial solutions or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem, I put here what I've find out for future reference. For reading data I used:

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
val sql = new SQLContext(sc)

var df = sql.read.format("es").load("my-index-*/log")
```

This allows you to fetch data even from multiple indexes (please note the `*`). If you need to run this code in `spark-shell` you can omit the first command, if you need to run this in `spark-submit` after compiling a jar (with SBT or Maven) you should include it.

After reading data, you can process it (maybe renaming a column with `var df = df.withColumnRenamed("@timestamp", "ts")`, for example).

When you have done processing your data, you can export them as Avro using the awesome [Databrick spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/tree/v2.0.1) library. You just have to compile it using SBT, after configuring you proxy if needed, running `$ sbt package` on the root of the project. Then under the `target/scala` path you can find your jar.

With this library you can export an Avro as following:

```
df.write
    .partitionBy("column")
    .mode("append")
    .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
    .save("my/hdfs/path")
```

That's it! You can omit the `partitionBy` function if you don't need partitioning, and you can use different mode than `append` for saving your data.

I hope this answer could help you.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to tell you the needed imports.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
```